# High score system from my iphone game

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, sql

I have this loop in PHP to select all my scores from my game from a MySQL table.

My query is:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE ";

    switch($type) {
        case "global":
            $sql .= "1 ";
            break;
        case "device":
            $sql .= "udid = '$udid' ";
            break;
        case "name":
            $sql .= "name = '$name' ";
            break;
    }

    $sql .= "ORDER BY $sort ";
    $sql .= "LIMIT $offset,$count ";

    $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
```

The `udid` is a unique identifier. And the loop:

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
                echo '<tr>
                        <td>
                        '.$rank.' 
                        </td>
                                                <td>
                        '.$row->name.'
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        '.$row->score.'
                        </td>
                                        <td>
                        '.$row->udid.'
                        </td>

                      </tr>';
                                 $rank++;
            }
```

My question is simple, so a person can see inside the game at which rank he is.
"How to select a rank from a `udid`, outside of the loop".

Perhaps making a new query which selects the rank from a `udid`, or set up a variable from in the loop?

Answer (score 1):

One option is writing a function that calculate the user's rank based on all the other's scores and returning it.
Then , calling it when the user wants to see his rank.

As far as I know , MMORPG games (for instance) have a `rank` field in their DB for each
player and they use a daily or hourly cron-job to update that rank.
So instead of running the 'calculate-the-rank' function each and every time a player
just want to see his rank, you'll just need to fetch the value of the field.

**EDIT:** code for the function (don't forget to add the `rank` field to your DB table)

File:

> cronjob_update_rank.php:

```
require 'config.php'; //Or whatever contains your config and DB connection.

$rank = 1; //The best player ranked as 1
$getMembers = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members ORDER BY `score` DESC");
while($mem = mysql_fetch_array($getMembers))
{
 mysql_query("UPDATE members SET rank='$rank' WHERE id='{$mem['id']}'");
 $rank++;
}
```

Please notice , it's just a sample code , you'll need to customize it for your needs.

Use your server panel to create a daily cronjob on that file. 
(or ask for your hosting provider support with it).

Comment: How could i make this function ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to query the database for the rank for player udid `1`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS rank
FROM tablename
WHERE score > (SELECT score FROM tablename WHERE udid = 1)
```

I'm assuming a higher score is better and you're only storing the highest score for each player.

With an index on `score` and `udid`, this should be pretty speedy.

What the query does is count the number of users who have a greater score than the selected user.

If a lower score is better, simply change it to this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS rank
FROM tablename
WHERE score < (SELECT score FROM tablename WHERE udid = 1)
```

Which counts the number of players with a lower score.

Read all about [MySQL indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html).

Comment: Actually, the lower the score is better. How can i change this so it will work ?? Also, what do you mean with an index on score?

Comment: So how would my table look like? Are rank and score variables or a field in my table? I'm getting errors all the time!