# Select identifier and show the row/rank from it

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [High score system from my iphone game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490066/high-score-system-from-my-iphone-game)

My query is:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE ";

    switch($type) {
        case "global":
            $sql .= "1 ";
            break;
        case "device":
            $sql .= "udid = '$udid' ";
            break;
        case "name":
            $sql .= "name = '$name' ";
            break;
    }

    $sql .= "ORDER BY $sort ";
    $sql .= "LIMIT $offset,$count ";

    $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
```

The udid is a unique identifier. And the loop:

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
                echo '<tr>
                        <td>
                        '.$rank.' 
                        </td>
                                                <td>
                        '.$row->name.'
                        </td>
                        <td>
                        '.$row->score.'
                        </td>
                                        <td>
                        '.$row->udid.'
                        </td>

                      </tr>';
                                 $rank++;
            }
```

This shows a table as following :

```
rank        name              score              udid
------------------------------------------------------
1           Joe               2.30101            49beeb956274dfb8406d66f7403dd4bf3d9c6da9 
2           John              2.41940            119d62e398bf6f1cea89b235b5c8ecf95255442e
3           Frank             2.64561            another id
4           Mitt              3.00101            another id
5           Sean              3.10001            another id
```

This works fine, but if I want to show a score and rank based on the udid, so if i want the udid: 119d62e398bf6f1cea89b235b5c8ecf95255442e i want to get the rank 2, name john and score 2.41940.

How can i do this ??

Joe

Comment: What if you run the same query, but change `LIMIT $offset, $count` to `LIMIT ". ($offset + $rank) .", 1`?

Comment: Or actually `($offset + $rank - 1)`

Answer (score 1):

Get the *score* of the row queried with the *udid* and use the following query to get the ranking

```
$sql = "SELECT Count(*) FROM $table WHERE score < '$score'";
```

The rank would be the value returned from the above query + 1